# Scrapy merging chained requests into one

Tags: python, scrapy

I have scenario where I am browsing a shop, going through 10s of pages. Then when I find the item that I want, I will add it to basket.

Finally I want to checkout the basket. The problem is that, with scrapy chaining, it wants to checkout the basket as many times as I have items in basket.

**How can I merge the chained requests into one, so after adding 10 items to basket, the checkout is called only once?**

```
def start_requests(self):
    params = getShopList()
    for param in params:
        yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://foo.bar/shop', callback=self.addToBasket,
                                 method='POST', formdata=param)


def addToBasket(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://foo.bar/addToBasket', callback=self.checkoutBasket,
                             method='POST',
                             formdata=param)

def checkoutBasket(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://foo.bar/checkout', callback=self.final, method='POST',
                             formdata=param)

def final(self):
    print("Success, you have purchased 59 items")
```

EDIT:

I tried to make the request in closed event, but it is not running into the request nor callback..

```
  def closed(self, reason):
        if reason == "finished":
            print("spider finished")
            return scrapy.Request('https://www.google.com', callback=self.finalmethod)
        print("Spider closed but not finished.")

    def finalmethod(self, response):
        print("finalized")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using Scrapy signals and `spider_idle` call.

> Sent when a spider has gone idle, which means the spider has no
>   further:

- requests waiting to be downloaded
- requests scheduled items being
- processed in the item pipeline

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html

```
from scrapy import signals, Spider

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'whatever'

    def start_requests(self):
        self.crawler.signals.connect(self.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle) ## notice this
        params = getShopList()
        for param in params:
            yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://foo.bar/shop', callback=self.addToBasket,
                                     method='POST', formdata=param)


    def addToBasket(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://foo.bar/addToBasket',
                                 method='POST', formdata=param)

    def spider_idle(self, spider): ## when all requests are finished, this is called
        req = scrapy.Request('https://foo.bar/checkout', callback=self.checkoutFinished)
        self.crawler.engine.crawl(req, spider)

    def checkoutFinished(self, response):
        print("Checkout finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can manually checkout when spider finished:

```
def closed(self, reason):
    if reason == "finished":
        return requests.post(checkout_url, data=param)
    print("Spider closed but not finished.")
```

See [closed](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.closed).

### update

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'whatever'

    def start_requests(self):
        params = getShopList()
        for param in params:
            yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://foo.bar/shop', callback=self.addToBasket,
                                     method='POST', formdata=param)


    def addToBasket(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://foo.bar/addToBasket',
                                 method='POST', formdata=param)

    def closed(self, reason):
        if reason == "finished":
            return requests.post(checkout_url, data=param)
        print("Spider closed but not finished.")
```

Comment: I liked your simple modification example, but that does not work? At the moment I do not understand, how to put "closed" into my code. I mean, how only one of the chains goes to checkout and other do not?

Comment: Um... It might doesn't work as spider sends requests concurrently. So "checkout" may sent before all "add" tasks done. I'm not very sure about it. So I just delete it. To put `closed` in your code, you just need to add it in your class. Your class should inherit from `scrapy.spiders.Spider`. I will give a full example.

Comment: Are you sure you can run requests after spider is finished? I tried to do post there, but it is not running into the request. I added the code to original post.

Comment: Yes you cannot use scrapy to send requests after spider is finishded. So I use another lib `requests` to send requests manually. Actually `closed` is ususally used to do some data processes such as storing all crawled data into file or filtering data. They are all offline operations. But as you want to do a final interaction with the server, you need to use an external lib.